# giving more weight to a feature using sklearn svm

Tags: python, svm

I 'm using svm to predict the label from the title of a book. However I want to give more weight to some features pre defined. For example, if the title of the book contains words like ***fairy, Alice*** I want to label them as children's books. I'm using word n-gram svm. Please suggest how to achieve this using sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one more feature vector in your training data, if the name of the book contains your predefined words then make it one otherwise zero.